# Executing code dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I would like to dynamically control code execution using a pointer, basically a function pointer without the stack frame.  Execution does not return to the calling location, but to a single point.

```
TopOfLoop:
...
Jump(x)


x1:
...
continue

x2:
...
continue

etc.
```

Is this possible in c#?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by using `goto` statement?

Reference at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

Though, it's not recommended way of coding. Try to use delegates instead:

```
 Func<T,TResutl> or Action<T>
```

- [Func Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)
- [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

### Sample:

```
using System;

public class LambdaExpression
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Func<string, string> convert = s => s.ToUpper();

      string name = "RIA Guy";
      Console.WriteLine(convert(name));   
   }
}
```

Comment: No, not with goto.  I believe pro3carp3 is asking about dynamic gotos, and C# does not support that.  You would either need to use a switch statement, or a delegate in the way Koistya recommends.

Comment: A goto is hard-coded.  I want to jump to a code-pointer, but it appears c# doesn't allow it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of function pointers, you'd probably want to have a look at delegates in c#. As to the rest of it, that has been covered by others.

Comment: A function pointer still creates and returns from a stack frame which isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This also looks like a SWITCH would work, and it would avoid the "goto" in code (though it would probably compile the same).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2(VS.71).aspx). I wouldn't, but it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly invoke a delegate with a callback, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the "Execution does not return to the calling location" part outside of a goto.